# Let the sum of the coefficients of the polynomial $(4x^2 - 4x + 3)^4(4 + 3x - 3x^2)^2$ be $S$ . Find $\frac{S}{16}$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, problem-solving, multinomial-coefficients

> Let the sum of the coefficients of the polynomial $(4x^2 - 4x + 3)^4(4 + 3x - 3x^2)^2$ be $S$ . Find $\frac{S}{16}$ .

- Actually I have absolutely no other idea on how to find this without opening up the brackets, and that will seem to be a very tiring work. I don't know any other method of getting the sum of the coefficients of this type of problems.

Wolfram Alpha gives the expansion of this expression :- https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284x%5E2+-+4x+%2B+3%29%5E4%284+%2B+3x+-+3x%5E2%29%5E2 .

That is ok, but here I want a short and an easy answer which can immediately tell me the value of $\frac{S}{16}$. Can anyone help me and give some hint or idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: What do you get when you substitute $x=1$ into a polynomial $p(x)$?

Comment: I would get $3^4 * 4^2$

Comment: The hint meant: What do you get when you substitute $x=1$ in the general polynomial $p(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + ... + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$? Forget about your particular polynomial for now.

Comment: @SouradipDas You're thinking of *the* polynomial. This hint is about *a* polynomial. When you understand how it works for any polynomial, your result for the polynomial will lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of coefficients of a polynomial $P(x)$ is $P(1)$.